# Folders not being added to Windows 7 Recent Places

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, history, user-folders

On a Windows 7 box, folders are not being added to Recent Places, even after files are opened from those folders.

Recent Places is always empty.

What setting was changed to prevent Recent Places from working, and how can it be enabled again?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of your current Folder Options

Comment: @Ramhound Sure, which tab?

Comment: The tab that indicates what your current folder options are set to. (When I looked on my Win 10 machine there was a single tab).  So all of them.